# Passing empty query to mongoDB using $match

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a dataset that I'm trying to create dynamic queries with. This is a sample of the data set.

```
db.test.insert({
    "_id" : ObjectId("58e574a768afb6085ec3a388"),
    "place": "A",
    "tests" : [
        {
            "name" : "1",
            "evaluation" : [
                {
                    "aHigh" : [1,2],
                    "aLow" : [ ],
                    "zHigh" : [ ],
                    "zLow" : [1,3]
                },
                {
                    "aHigh" : [1,4],
                    "aLow" : [2],
                    "zHigh" : [ 3],
                    "zLow" : [ ]
                },
                {
                    "aHigh" : [ ],
                    "aLow" : [1,2,3],
                    "zHigh" : [1,2,3,4],
                    "zLow" : [ ]
                },]
            }
            ]
        })
db.test.insert({
    "_id" : ObjectId("58eba09e51f7f631dd24aa1c"),
    "place": "B",
    "tests" : [
        {
            "name" : "2",
            "evaluation" : [
                {
                    "aHigh" : [2],
                    "aLow" : [3 ],
                    "zHigh" : [ ],
                    "zLow" : [1,2,3,4]
                },
                {
                    "aHigh" : [ ],
                    "aLow" : [ ],
                    "zHigh" : [ ],
                    "zLow" : [3,4]
                },
                {
                    "aHigh" : [1,2],
                    "aLow" : [3,4],
                    "zHigh" : [ ],
                    "zLow" : [1,2,3,4]
                },]
            }
            ]
        })
```

The setup in total uses `nodejs` and `angularjs`, but the question only pertains to `mongoDB`. I have a set of selector boxes populated with the values contained in each of a specific field. For example, `"place"` has a selector that contains the values `"A"` and `"B"`.

The default behavior of the search boxes is that they have a placeholder and no selected data passed to the model. This means that when I pass the query on load using the output of the model to `mongoDB`, I'm actually passing a `{}`. However, when I make a selection in the search box, then it passes a value.

In my `mongoDB` query, I must use `aggregate` (for reasons that exceed the scope of the question), and therefore I must use `$match`. Here is some sample code.

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { $match: { place: {$in: [ <whateverQuery> ]}}},
    { $unwind: "$tests"},
    { $sortByCount: "$tests.name"}
])
```

The expected output looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : "1", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "2", "count" : 1 }
```

How can I modify my approach so that passing nothing to the query returns everything?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but you need to programmatically build your $match query so that you end up with `$match: {}`.

Comment: I see that `$match: {}` gives me the desired output. Passing `$match : { place: {$in: []}}` does not. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: `$in` must match at least one value in the array; so with an empty array there's no possible match.

Comment: Use $ifNull inside $match to decide which value to pass.  Visit - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/